# Is it possible to read the Z component of a SDO_POINT using Hibernate-Spatial over Oracle?

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, oracle-spatial, hibernate-spatial

I am using Hibernate-Spatial to map a `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point` field in an entity to an `SDO_POINT` field in my Oracle 11g table.

The column on the table is defined as :

```
"SST_COORDINATES" "MDSYS"."SDO_GEOMETRY"
```

The column is mapped as :

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
@Column(name = "SST_COORDINATES")
@QueryType(PropertyType.NONE)
private Point coordinates;
```

(The `@QueryType` annotation is from QueryDSL so probably not relevant, but I included it for the sake of completeness)

Here is an example of content for the SDO_POINT column (as seen in SQLDeveloper) :

```
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(3001,21781,MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(649300,246800,399.4),NULL,NULL)
```

It all works fine except that **I can't read the Z component of the point**. The `Point` class only has `getX()` and `getY()` accessors.

I tried to access the underlying `org.hibernate.spatial.jts.mgeom.MCoordinate` object, via the method `getCoordinate()`, but the Z value is equal to the Y value.

Can anybody help me get the Z value using Hibernate-Spatial ? Or is it just not supported ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found the bug causing this and files the following JIRA issue : http://www.hibernatespatial.org/jira/browse/HIBSPA-117

It will be fixed in a future release.